# Realm NSInternalInconsistencyException When Starting App Offline

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, realm, realm-mobile-platform

The lifecycle I am testing is: `Start App Online -> Add item -> go offline -> kill the app -> open app -> add item -> go online`. If I try adding a new item after going online I get `'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 9 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update'` Not sure why it believes there are only 0 rows in section 0.

Relevant Code:

```swift
let realm = try! Realm()
let owners = try! Realm().objects(OwnerList.self).first?.list

// Notification token defined in viewDidLoad()

self.notificationToken = self.owners?.addNotificationBlock { [unowned self] changes in
        switch changes {
        case .initial:
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
            // Query results have changed, so apply them to the UITableView
            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: insertions.map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }, with: .automatic)
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: deletions.map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }, with: .automatic)
            self.tableView.reloadRows(at: modifications.map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }, with: .none)
            self.tableView.endUpdates()
        case .error(let error):
            print("Notification Error", error)
            break
        }
}

// Helper Function when inserting item

func insertItem() throws {
    self.realm.beginWrite()
    let owner = Owner().generate()
    self.owners?.insert(owner, at: (owners?.count)!)
    self.tableView.insertRows(at: [[0, (owners?.count)!-1]], with: .automatic)
    try self.realm.commitWrite(withoutNotifying: [self.notificationToken!])
}
```

Comment: Why remove the notification when you commit the write? the notification will take care of the tableview inserts/deletions on its own. Also, if you keep tableView.insertRows it takes an array of IndexPaths, change to insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: , section: )]. Don't think it will solve problem but I noticed this when reading your code and figured I'd mention it.

Comment: Thanks @JustinM for the response. I don't want to notify the token because the insertion should be immediate on the device, not a response from the sync server. This was recently added by Realm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, make sure you set your tableview delegate and datasource in `viewDidLoad()` not `viewWillAppear()`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't insert rows until write transaction is committed because write transactions could potentially fail.

Try to move

```
self.tableView.insertRows(at: [[0, (owners?.count)!-1]], with: .automatic)
```

after `realm.commitWrite(..)`.

Also make sure your tableview datasource methods return correct values.

Comment: Ahh good point thanks, it doesn't seem to have fixed the problem but very helpful! Is there a way to check if the commit was successful? Or does simply putting the insertion after the commit prevent it from being run if the commit fails?

Comment: If the transaction failed to commit you get an error with all the info.

Comment: Okay, just to clarify, if the transaction fails, it exits the method?